# iCarousel in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm trying to build a character selection menu similar to Crossy Road's one (as you can see [here](http://www.therockstargamers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/crossy-road-character-select.png)). So I found this [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel), which would help me with all of it, but everything I read talk about implementing it to a `ViewController`, which isn't my case. I'm using `GameScene` and I didn't found anything talking about it. Is there anyway I could implement it to my game? or even another effect similar to the character selection menu I mentioned above?

---

### Attempt (beyowulf)

You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d62tx0q305gjhcz/AACPHvNCAkO3SrYcFQhGkkhsa?dl=0).

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var show = SKSpriteNode()
    var hide = SKSpriteNode()

    func showCharPicker(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showCharPicker", object: nil)
    }
    func hideCharPicker(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideCharPicker", object: nil)
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        print("didMoveToView")

        show = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "show")
        show.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        show.position = CGPointZero
        addChild(show)

        hide = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hide")
        hide.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        hide.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - hide.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
        addChild(hide)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches{

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

            if node == show{
                print("show")
                showCharPicker()
            }
            else if node == hide{
                print("hide")
                hideCharPicker()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate{

    var squaresArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    @IBOutlet weak var carousel: iCarousel!

    deinit{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func showCarousel(){
        self.carousel.hidden = false
    }
    func hideCarousel(){
        self.carousel.hidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure iCarousel
        carousel.dataSource = self
        carousel.delegate = self
        carousel.type = .CoverFlow
        carousel.reloadData()

        self.carousel.hidden = true

        // Register showCarousel and hideCarousel functions
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showCarousel), name: "showCharPicker", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hideCarousel), name: "hideCharPicker", object: nil)

        // Configure view
        let skView = SKView()
        self.view.insertSubview(skView, belowSubview: self.carousel)
        skView.frame = self.view.bounds

        // Additionals
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        // Configure scene
        let scene = GameScene(size:self.view.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.size = self.view.bounds.size

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    //iCarousel
    override func awakeFromNib(){
        super.awakeFromNib()
        squaresArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["square1","square2","square3"])
    }
    func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int{
        return squaresArray.count
    }
    func carousel(carousel:iCarousel, didSelectItemAtIndex index:NSInteger){
        //self.hideCarousel()
    }
    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView{

        var itemView: UIImageView

        if (view == nil){
            itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:200))
            itemView.contentMode = .Center
        }
        else{
            itemView = view as! UIImageView;
        }

        itemView.image = UIImage(named: "\(squaresArray.objectAtIndex(index))")
        return itemView
    }
    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

        if (option == .Spacing){
            return value * 2
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

---

### What's happening:

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: You might want to think about putting the carousel on the main view controller (where the scene is added), and then use a protocol or function within the scene's class to load the characters to show up within the carousel

Comment: I edit my question with your suggestion. Could you take a look, please? =)

Comment: The problem is: this `itemView`, as a `UIImageView`, isn't letting me use an array, so I could use `squares` array value; instead of `UIImage(named: "page.png")` =(

Comment: by `squares` I mean: `[UIImage(named: "square1")!, UIImage(named: "square2")!, UIImage(named: "square3")!]`

Comment: Look at your carousel:viewForItemAtIndex... And think about how you could use the index for the array item(s). Then set the imageView.image = [item in array]

Comment: I changed it from `Int` to `UIImage`, but it kept saying: `"Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'iCarouselDataSource'`. Sorry, I'm very new to programming, so I don't know much of it =(

Comment: You can't change the methods on a delegate method. That's why you're getting those errors. I'd suggest going back to looking at delegate methods on Apple, or finding a tutorial on how to use icarousel before tackling a moderate task such as that.

Comment: I edit my question. Could you take a look, please? =)

Comment: Do you mean to be hiding the carousel in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Sorry if what I'm saying doesn't make any sense, but I meant to: in `GameScene` call `showCarousel` (to show the carousel in the game) or `hideCarousel` (to hide it) functions. I'd be calling these functions by using `NSNotifications`.

Comment: This hiding thing is another step that I'm aiming. First, I'm trying to make this carousel work in `GameViewController`, since it was working perfectly in a SingleViewApp's `ViewController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSNotifications to show your character picker. You just need to observe the notifications posted by your `SKScene`. Your `viewDidLoad` should look something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    carousel.type = .CoverFlow
    carousel.reloadData()

    let spriteKitView = SKView()
    spriteKitView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.insertSubview(spriteKitView, belowSubview: self.carousel)

    spriteKitView.showsFPS = true
    spriteKitView.showsNodeCount = true
    spriteKitView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    self.gameScene = GameScene(size:self.view.bounds.size)
    self.gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    self.gameScene.imageName = self.images[0] as! String

    self.carousel.hidden = true
    spriteKitView.presentScene(self.gameScene)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showCarousel), name: gameScene.kShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

You'll want to implementing `carousel(carousel:iCarousel, didSelectItemAtIndex index:NSInteger)` so you know what is selected, and so you can return to game play. For example:

```
func carousel(carousel:iCarousel, didSelectItemAtIndex index:NSInteger)
{
    self.gameScene.imageName = self.images[index] as! String
    self.hideCarousel()
}
```

You also need to remove observing before your view controller is deallocated.

```
deinit
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Your `SKScene` can then post a notifications:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var imageName = "square1"{
        didSet{
            self.hidden = false
            self.childNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
        }
    }

    let kShowNotification = "showPicker"

    var childNode = SKSpriteNode()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.childNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
        self.childNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        self.childNode.position = CGPointZero
        self.addChild(self.childNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.showCharPicker()
    }

    func showCharPicker()
    {
        self.hidden = true
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

}
```

If you want to change hit detection, you need to subclass the view for which you need it to change. This case your `iCarousel` view.

You can then either override `hitTest` or `pointInside`. I've created an `iCarousel` subclass and overrode `pointInside` to only return true when the point is inside one of the carousel's `contentView`'s subviews.

```
class CarouselSubclass: iCarousel {

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var inside = false
        for view in self.contentView.subviews
        {
            inside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)
            if inside
            {
                return inside
            }
        }
        return inside
    }
}
```

You need to remember to change the class of your carousel in interface builder and update your outlet as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `MySpriteKitSceneSubclass`? Can't I do it by only calling it from `GameScene`? I mean, I already have more than a thousand lines of code in `GameScene`. I was wondering to simply implement this iCarousel as it is in [Crossy Road](http://www.therockstargamers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/crossy-road-character-select.png), to `GameViewController` (since I can't do it directly in `GameScene`) and, by using `NSNotifications`, call `GameViewController` functions from `GameScene`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `MySpriteKitSceneSubclass` as a placeholder. The template `SpriteKit` project has `GameScene` as the default subclass of `SceneKit`, so in your instance that is what I'm referring to. There wasn't any `GameScene` in the project you linked to. If you know what to do, what is your question?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think that's what you want, but it seems like you already know what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry if I seem to be rude. It really wasn't my intention. I updated my question with your answer, but it isn't showing the carousel effect. I made a little image to express what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's basically: game shows up > char picker shows up above > select one of the images > if selected, hide it > if not, do nothing

Comment: That's fine. Did you try the code I posted? Just remove `self.hidden = true` from `showCharPicker` and `self.hidden = false` from `didSet`

Comment: I did, but it's only showing up the square1 image, instead of all the squares images and it's without the carousel effect =(

Comment: I updated my question with some screenshots of whats happening =)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/bgayman/SpriteKitCarousel/tree/master/swiftexample)

Comment: Sorry if I bother you. Thank you for your attention =)

Comment: Hi! Sorry for coming here again, but I'm stuck trying to interact with `GameScene`'s buttons when carousel popped up. I saw that there's a "clear color" set in `ViewController`, allowing me to see what's behind - `GameScene`, but I guess it acts like a transparent background which won't allow me to interact with these buttons.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can check my the git repository as well.

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Thank you!! Could a ask one more thing? I can call `hideCarousel()` when any of the images are selected by using `didSelectItemAtIndex`, but how can I make it specific? I mean, different actions when selecting each image.

Comment: Don't you say `if index == 0` do something `if index == 1` do something else?

Comment: That's exactly it!! Thank you again!! If I could, I'd vote this question up three times or more.

Comment: can you please do a tutorial or something? i can't make it work for some reason my carousel is getting stucked on top-left corner and i can't move it, and also the swipe is only possible within a tiny boundary...