# iCarousel on Game Swift+SpriteKit not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, icarousel

I'm trying to add an [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/) to my game that will be displayed in the MainMenu, where you will be able to select an item and unlock others while you play and do more progress within the game.

Tried looking into a few tutorials but i still have some problems and i can't figure it out.

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756502/using-icarousel-in-a-game) I based my current code on and also this [github](https://github.com/bgayman/SpriteKitCarousel/tree/master/swiftexample)

But the structure on that "SpriteKit iCarousel" github is different than mine too.

I can make the carousel be displayed but doesn't even work, and is also located on top-left of the screen like "stucked" for some reason.

So this is my **GameViewController.swift** code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {


    var imageArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var selectedIndex: Int!
    var carousel : iCarousel!

    deinit{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func showCarousel(){
        carousel.hidden = false
    }
    func hideCarousel(){
        carousel.hidden = true
    }

    override func awakeFromNib(){
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.imageArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["white","white2","white3"])
    }

    func carousel(carousel:iCarousel, didSelectItemAtIndex index:NSInteger)   {

        let scene = MenuScene(size:self.view.bounds.size)
        scene.imageName = self.imageArray[index] as! String
        self.hideCarousel()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.authenticateLocalPlayer()
        self.setupCarousel()
    }

    func setupCarousel() {
        carousel = iCarousel()
        carousel.dataSource = self
        carousel.delegate = self
        carousel.type = .Linear
        carousel.reloadData()

        let spriteKitView = SKView()
        spriteKitView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)
//        self.view.insertSubview(spriteKitView, belowSubview: self.carousel) // this is showing an empty gray box 
        self.view.addSubview(self.carousel)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showCarousel), name: "showBallPicker", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hideCarousel), name: "hideBallPicker", object: nil)
    }

    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

        if (option == .Spacing){
            return value * 2
        }

        return value
    }

    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!

        if view == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        }else{
            imageView = view as! UIImageView
        }

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.objectAtIndex(index))")

        return imageView
    }

    func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        if skView.scene == nil {
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsPhysics = false
            skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true

            let menuScene = MenuScene(size: CGSizeMake(375,667))
            menuScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            menuScene.imageName = self.imageArray[0] as! String

            self.hideCarousel()
            skView.presentScene(menuScene)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        if let skView = self.view as? SKView {
            skView.presentScene(nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        if let skView = self.view as? SKView {
            skView.presentScene(nil)
        }
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

And this is what i'm doing on **MenuScene.swift**

```
var childNode = SKSpriteNode()
var imageName = "white"{
    didSet{
        self.childNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)
    }
}

func showBallPicker(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showBallPicker", object: nil)
}

override init(size: CGSize) {
     // here im supposed to create a childNode SKSpriteNode, but for what? it only adds the same image of the carousel and that's it.
    self.childNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
    self.childNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    self.childNode.zPosition = 30
    self.childNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(self.childNode)

}
```

And then, on touchesEnded i'm calling from a button touch self.showBallPicker() to display the carousel.

As I said before, it's adding the carousel, but not even working and on top-left corner.

How can I achieve this? Once I can make it display properly, I can handle the rest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the frame of the carousel or setting constraints on it.

Try changing your `setupCarousel` method to:

```
func setupCarousel() {
        carousel = iCarousel()
        carousel.dataSource = self
        carousel.delegate = self
        carousel.type = .Linear
        carousel.reloadData()
        // turn off autoresizing mask
        carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.carousel)
        // Add constraints
        carousel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
        carousel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        carousel.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        carousel.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showCarousel), name: "showBallPicker", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hideCarousel), name: "hideBallPicker", object: nil)
}
```

### Update

These constraints will pin the carousel to the edges of your view controller's view. If you want to position it differently, you could, for example, replace those constraints with something like:

```
carousel.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
carousel.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100).active = true
carousel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor).active = true
carousel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(200.0).active = true
```

This will center the carousel horizontally and place the carousel 100 points up from the center vertically. The carousel will be the same width as it's superview but will always be 200 points tall. You can look at Apple's documentation for more options for using anchors to create constraints.

If you want to add labels to your carousel items you should do that in `viewForItemAtIndex`. You can create a simple `UIView` subclass that will hold a `UIImageView` and `UILabel` and return that instead of just a `UIImageView`. For example:

```
class CarouselItem: UIView {
    let imageView:UIImageView =
    {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()

    let label:UILabel =
    {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit()
    {
        self.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.addSubview(self.label)

        self.imageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor).active = true
        self.imageView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor).active = true
        self.imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.widthAnchor).active = true
        self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).active = true

        self.label.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).active = true
        self.label.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.centerXAnchor).active = true
    }
}
```

Now in `viewForItemAtIndex`

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var carouselItem: CarouselItem!

        if view == nil {
            carouselItem = CarouselItem(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250))
            carouselItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }else{
            carouselItem = view as! CarouselItem
        }

        carouselItem.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.objectAtIndex(index))")
        carouselItem.label.text = "Some Text"

        return carouselItem
    }
```

Comment: ohh beyowulf! gonna try it out when i get home!! thanks for replying :)

Comment: omgggg, you are a genius!!!! you solved it! now is placed correctly!, do you know how can i add effects to the iCarousel? is it possible? maybe a "zoom" to the one you're about to select? thank you soooo much Beyowulf. I knew you could solve it :)

Comment: mmm this is weird. When i select an item in the carousel, it shows up the ad banner i hid and the buttons doesn't work anymore, do you know could that be?

Comment: Isn't the zoom essentially the `.Rotary` type? I don't see an ad banner in your code, so I'm not sure. It seems like you are instantiating a new `MenuScene` in `didSelectItemAtIndex` here: `let scene = MenuScene(size:self.view.bounds.size)`. Seems like you should be saying `if let skView = self.view as? SKView, let menuScene = skView.scene as? MenuScene { menuScene. imageName = self.imageArray[index] as! String }`. That is just getting a reference to the already instantiated and presented scene and then setting its `imageName` property.

Comment: Nice, it worked, now the ad is not shown anymore. But still, i got a back button in my menuScene that when i tap it, it doesn't go back anymore. I still got something failing in there. PS: Tested the rotary, it looks nice but is like a circle, i just wanted to increase the size of the one in the middle, i can check on that later. No worries.

Comment: Yea, definitely.. the buttons in the scene bugs when i do carousel.hidden = false to show it. Otherwise, it won't be buggy. And also i noticed, it bugs even when they are displayed, like.. i dont need to touch any item on it to make my buttons bug. That's weird.

Comment: Another thing, if i hideCarousel() when i tap on a ball, so it hides the carousel, the buttons are back to normal... so this is something that is happening when im showing the carousel. PS: I fixed the zoom effect thing ;)

Comment: You should look at the other part where I talk about subclassing `iCarousel` so touch events outside of the carousel's items are passed to the `SKView`.

Comment: You were right, it works perfectly fine! I still got 2 more question tho, if you dont mind helping and i swear i got nothing else to bother you haha. 1) I saw you gave me some constraints to place the carousel in midX,midY. What if i want to put it for example in midY - 100? or midY - 200? 2) If i want to add some labels and buttons to purchase carousel items, should i add it inside the subview? or in the SKView would be fine?